# Lombok @Log and @Slf4j not have error method

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I want to use Lombok `@Log` or `@Slf4j` but when I create:

```
@Log
public class Test{
    public Test(){
       log.error("Something's wrong here");
    }
}
```

in log, I do not have got an error method. I have `info` and `warning`

I have only `log()` method.

I tried to add mave dependency to Slf4j library, but it did not help.

Answer (score 4):

Lombok's [@Log](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/extern/java/Log.html)
annotation inserts

```
private static final java.util.logging.Logger log = ...;
```

See the javadoc of [java.util.logging.Logger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html).
You are right, it has no `error(String msg)` method.
But it has a [`severe(String msg)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#severe(java.lang.String)) method
and a [`throwing(String, String, Throwable)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#throwing(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable)) doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found that spring boot include libries automaticly. I add this libs to my not spring project and all work fine

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

LogTest

```
@Slf4j
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    public class LogTest {
        public void test(){
            log.error("fdfzsdf");
        }
    }
```